# Unable to run PySpark in Jupyter Notebook - Linux

Tags: python, java, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run PySpark on my Jupyter Notebook locally on a server not connected to the internet. I installed PySpark and Java using the following:

```
conda install pyspark-3.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
conda install openjdk-8.0.332-h166bdaf_0.tar.bz2
```

When I do a `!java -version` in my notebook, I get

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.62.0.19-CA-linux64) (build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)
```

When I run `!which java`, I get

```
/root/anaconda3/bin/java
```

My code is as follows.

```
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/root/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-3.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0/site_packages/pyspark"
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/root/anaconda3"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[2] pyspark-shell"

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().set('spark.driver.host','127.0.0.1')
sc = SparkContext(master='local', appName='Test', conf=conf)
```

The error I got was (a snippet of it because I'm manually typing it here):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: abc: abc: Name or service not known
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: abc: Name or service not known
...

Runtime Error: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

"abc" is my server's hostname. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

Based on the error message `java.net.UnknownHostException: abc: abc: Name or service not known`, I suspected Java did not recognize my server hostname `abc`. So I added it to `/etc/hosts` under the loopback IP `127.0.0.1`, and now I can run pyspark.